# How to automate a Java Swing application through Silk Test Classic?

Tags: java, swing, silktest

I have no clue how to start automating a **Java Swing application**. Till date, I have worked only on web applications using **Silk Test Classic** with the **Open Agent**.

I just need the following and then I am sure I can start on my own:

- A sample Java Swing application
- How to kickstart automating it in Silk Test Classic (any URL or
  documentation). I have already gone through the Microfocus documentation
  but it didn't help me much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of Swing sample applications out there (just ask your favorite search engine) - for example [Oracle's list of Swing samples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/).

If you are already familiar with Silk Test Classic and using the Open Agent, that's great - a lot of the concepts are the same for testing web applications and Swing applications.

I guess the easiest way to start is to pick a Swing application and record a new test script against it. Once you see the recorded script, it will probably look familiar.

To learn more about Silk Test's Swing support, you can also look at the [documentation](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.borland.silktest.doc/STCLASSIC-B287F5B6-OVERVIEW-OF-JAVA-AWT-SWING-APPLICATIONS.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Let me try your sample link. Will get back to you.

Comment: Finally I was able to automate a swing application. Thanks!